# Signal Strength of Bluetooth devices using Web-Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, p2p, web-bluetooth

I am looking to obtain the bluetooth strength (RSSI or similar) of a signal using a web-based application (in this case attempting with the [Web-Bluetooth API)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API). From what I've seen this feature is not supported in a browser (yet at least).

The result was intended to be used on a mobile device rather than a desktop but if there is a solution for either I am unaware at the current minute. Since I cannot see much on the matter of it other than it working within downloaded/compiled mobile apps (which I guess I will have to resort to if this is completely unachievable).

This would also apply to if HTML5 p2p connection strength if that was an obtainable value as well.

Maybe I have completely missed something out and my googling skills are terrible, otherwise any relevant links / information is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently implemented the [`watchAdvertisements()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-watchadvertisements) API that will enable the page to listen for advertisement packets from the device. When a packet is received, an `advertisementreceived` Event is fired on the device, and the Event contains the RSSI and TX Power of the device. You can give this API a try by enabling chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features in Chrome 85.0.4165 or higher.